# Currently possible to add a .NET-Back-End to Azure Mobile App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, xamarin.forms

I was following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#create-app).

There its says this:

1. Open the New Project dialog (from File > New > Project...).
2. Expand Templates > Visual C#, and select Web.
3. Select ASP.NET Web Application.
4. Fill in the project name. Then click OK.
5. Under ASP.NET 4.5.2 Templates, select Azure Mobile App. Check Host in the cloud to create a mobile backend in the cloud to which you can publish this project.
6. Click OK.

But this is not working as expected...

[image]

[image]

Searching for the transistion I've found this: https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/transition-of-azure-mobile-services/

But how can I add this to "App-Services" rather than "Mobile-Service" ?

---

**EDIT 1:**

Even with the updated SDK there is no "Azure Mobile App".

[image]

Or am I wrong ?

Comment: have you tried updating azure sdk?

Comment: @4c74356b41 well that might be an issue :D thx. I will try if that helps

Comment: @4c74356b41 can you help me again ?

Comment: What template do I have to use here (see Edit 1) ?

Comment: Azure Mobile Service, probably?

Comment: If I do that "host in the cloud" is unavailable and it just starts creating my project. How to attach that to my existing mobile app ?

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, you need to use Azure App Service, right, so you need to create basically anything that can be deployed to a webapp. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve thou

Comment: Alright I got it. Seems like they did some major changes here and the connection to the Azure service is done now post build ( on deploy ). Anyways thanks for your help. If u feel like posting the "update SDK" as an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to this problem was: Update the SDK to the latest version. ;)